# Codeception: How to use amLoggedAs in a Helper class

Tags: laravel-5, codeception

I am trying to make a helper class for my codeception functional tests that makes it quicker to specify logging in as a super user.  Here is my helper:

```
class Laravel5Helper extends Laravel5 {
    public function amSuperAdmin() {
        $this->amLoggedAs(['username' => 'super', 'password'=> 'password']);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  When I use the declaration `$this->amLoggedAs(['username' => 'super', 'password'=> 'password']);` in a normal test it logs in the user as expected, but when I use `$I->amSuperAdmin()` it seems to fail to do so.  There are no errors; the method is visible in my generated FunctionalTester class.  When I trace the code I can see the authentication passing in the Laravel5::amLoggedAs method, but the test gets redirected to my app's login page as though authentication failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is a different object than the Laravel5 module,
you should get the instance of Laravel5 module and call its method:

```
class Laravel5Helper extends \Codeception\Module {
    public function amSuperAdmin() {
        $this->getModule('Laravel5')->amLoggedAs(['username' => 'super', 'password'=> 'password']);
    }
}
```